# cv::Mat to pcl::PointCloud, to data as unsigned short *?

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a `cv::Mat` that is a depth image.

I am converting it to a PCL pointcloud like this:

```
PointCloud::Ptr RGBDtoPCL3(cv::Mat depth_image)
{
    PointCloud::Ptr pointcloud(new PointCloud);

    float fx = 481.20;
    float fy = 480.00;
    float cx = 319.50;
    float cy = 239.50;

    float factor = 1;
    depth_image.convertTo(depth_image, CV_32F); // convert the image data to float type 

    if (!depth_image.data) {
        std::cerr << "No depth data!!!" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pointcloud->width = depth_image.cols; //Dimensions must be initialized to use 2-D indexing 
    pointcloud->height = depth_image.rows;

    pointcloud->points.resize(pointcloud->height * pointcloud->width);
    pointcloud->resize(pointcloud->width*pointcloud->height);

    for (int v = 0; v < depth_image.rows; v++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < depth_image.cols; u++)
        {
            float Z = depth_image.at<float>(v, u) / factor;

            PointT p;
            p.z = Z;
            p.x = (u - cx) * Z / fx;
            p.y = (v - cy) * Z / fy;

            p.z = p.z / 1000;
            p.x = p.x / 1000;
            p.y = p.y / 1000;

            pointcloud->points.push_back(p);

        }
    }

    return pointcloud;

}
```

I am also getting the data from the Mat like this:

```
unsigned short* dataMat1 = depth_image.ptr<unsigned short>();
```

I then do some processing on the point cloud.

What i need to do now is convert the pointcloud into an unsigned short* that matches the dataMat1 above.

What would this conversion look like? Do I need to convert back to a `cv::Mat` and then use its ptr? Or can i just convert from pointcloud to unsigned short *?

Thank you.